# How do I put an object inside another object based on the same key?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I am working with Reactjs and my data looks like this:

```
const this.state.singlePost = [{
        name: 'Johnny',
        age: 20,
        birthPlace: 'Germany'
    },
    {
        name: 'Samuel',
        age: 22,
        birthPlace: 'France'
    }
]

let this.state.post = [{
        email: 'john@gm.co',
        number: 4567887654
    },
    {
        email: 'samuel@gm.co',
        number: 0987655881
    },
]
```

I want to make something like this:

```
let editedPost = [{
        name: 'Johnny',
        age: 20,
        birthPlace: 'Germany',
        email: 'john@gm.co',
        number: 4567887654
    },
    {
        name: 'Samuel',
        age: 22,
        birthPlace: 'France',
        email: 'samuel@gm.co',
        number: 0987655881
    }
]
```

It might be a stupid question, but I got stuck for a few hours on this, Could somebody help me please? I have 5 items in `this.state.singlePost` and 10 items in `this.state.post`. How do I put the stuff in `this.state.singlePost` into `this.state.post` just like the way I did in `editedPost`?

Comment: So are these all just variables or are the first 2 supposed to be part of react component state? Either way the current syntax isn't correct. Read this to understand how to work with react state https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you would have a common key between the two objects that you would be able to merge on as without you will be relying on matching the index of objects.

```js
let post = [
  {email: 'john@gm.co',
   number: 4567887654},
  {email: 'samuel@gm.co',
   number: 987655881}
  ]

 let singlePost = [ 
    {name: 'Johnny', age: 20, birthPlace: 'Germany'}, 
    {name: 'Samuel', age: 22, birthPlace: 'France'}
  ]

let newList = post.map((item, i) => ({...item, ...singlePost[i]}))

console.log(newList)
```

Output:

```js
[
    {
        email:"john@gm.co",
        number:4567887654,
        name:"Johnny",
        age:20,
        birthPlace:"Germany"
    },
    {
        email:"samuel@gm.co",
        number:987655881,
        name:"Samuel",
        age:22,
        birthPlace:"France"
    }
]
```

There is many ways to do this in Javascript. The way I chose prevents mutation of data, which may be something you are concerned with when using React.